# How do you put content in xml file using file_put_contents in sub-child element

Tags: php, xml, file-put-contents

I know how to put content to child element I google and can't find solution to put content to sub-child element. I have following structure in my xml file

```
<pagevalues>
    <ac>
        <acb1/>
        <acb2/>
        <acb3/>
        <acb4/>
        <acb5/>
        <acpc/>
    </ac>
........
.....
</pagevalues>
```

this is the code to put value in xml file

```
$xml->$ac = $actotal;
file_put_contents("$url", $xml->asXML());
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it

$xml->ac->acb1 = $actotal;
    file_put_contents("$url", $xml->asXML());